# Is this a Grails Constructor

Tags: grails

I have inherited some grails code, and am trying to understand what the nature of the **create** method below is.  Is it some sort of grails keyword constructor for the Attribute property, owned by the **AttributeService**?  I don't see where the **create** method is called anywhere.  Thanks.

```
class AttributeService {

    boolean transactional = false

    def uiKey2Attribute = [:]
    def internalName2Attribute = [:]

    def Attribute create(String internalName, String displayName) {
        Attribute attribute = new Attribute();
        attribute.setInternalName(internalName);
        attribute.setUiKey(internalName.replaceAll(' ', '_'))
        attribute.setDisplayName(displayName);
        return attribute;
    }

}
```

Comment: It's a little confusing because the return type is defined both as `def` and `Attribute`. It's best to use one, and in this case Groovy ignores the `def`. Use `def` when you don't care what the type is, or the type when you do, but never both since it's redundant and confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a public method inside a service that returns a new instance of `Attribute` applying some rules.

Search for "attributeService" to see where this is used, since Grails use dependency injection  on his artefacts (controller, taglib...).

Considering that a controller should be as light as possible, just handling requests, a service is a good place to manipulate domain classes (create, save, delete and so on), and it's probably what AttributeService does.

[Here is the Petclinic](https://github.com/grails-samples/petclinic) Spring example ported to Grails, maybe it will help you to understand the concept of controllers and services.

**EDIT**
To add some excitement to your exploration, this is how the service class would look like when made groovier:

```
class AttributeService {
    /**
     * This property decides whether the service class
     * is transactional by default or not
     */
    static transactional = false

    /**
     * Grails service class is singleton by default
     * So class level variables maintain state across the requests.
     * Beware of using global variables
     */
    def uiKey2Attribute = [:]
    def internalName2Attribute = [:]

    /**
     * You can either use def or the actual class as the return type
     * Best practice is the provide the signature of method fully typed
     * if you already know what the return type would be.
     * This is self documenting.
     * And would not confuse other developer if you use something like
     *  def create(internalName, displayName) which is valid in Groovy as well.
     */
    Attribute create(String internalName, String displayName) {
        Attribute attribute = new Attribute()
        attribute.setInternalName(internalName)
        attribute.setUiKey(internalName.replaceAll(' ', '_'))
        attribute.setDisplayName(displayName)
        //return is optional
        //last statement in a method is always returned
        attribute
    }
}
```